# RequireJS is loading scripts that are not needed on all pages

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Require.js loads every module on every page, so I get JavaScript errors on pages that don't need the loaded scripts. Specifically, the news-filter.js is loading on my search page, and causing the error:
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "li." from this line in the news-filter.js

```
 $("ul.mediaListing").children("li."+chosenYear).filter("."+chosenCategory).each(function(c) {
```

Am I missing somthing about how reqire.js determines what scripts are needed on each page?
My main.js file is:

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: [system-view:internal]"/render/file.act?path=/assets/scripts/"[/system-view:internal] [system-view:external]"/assets/scripts/"[/system-view:external], 

    paths: {
       "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min",
        "velocity": "libs/velocity/velocity",
        "bgstretch": "plugins/background-stretch/background-stretch",
        "campus-map": "modules/campus-map",
        "velocity-ui": "libs/velocity/velocity.ui",
        "slick": "plugins/slick/slick",
        "iscroll": "plugins/iscroll/iscroll",
        "dotdotdot": "plugins/dotdotdot/jquery.dotdotdot.min.umd",
        "select": "plugins/select/select",
        "accordion": "modules/accordion",
        "news-filter": "modules/news-filter",
        "codebird": "modules/codebird",
        "social-feed": "modules/social-feed"
    },

    shim: {

        "slick": ["jquery"],
        "select": ["jquery"],
        "bgstretch": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "accordion": ["jquery"],
        "codebird": ["jquery"],
        "social-feed": {
            dep: ["jquery", "codebird"],
            exports: "displayFeed"
        },
        "campus-map": {
            deps: [ "jquery" ]
        },
        "velocity": {
            deps: [ "jquery" ]
        },
        "velocity-ui": {
            deps: [ "velocity" ]
        }
        },
         map: {
            '*': {
                'jQuery': 'jquery'
            }
        }

});

requirejs(

    ['jquery', 'modules/utils', 'modules/custom.ui', 'libs/jquery/paginga.jquery', "modules/social-feed", "modules/news-filter"], 
    function ($, utils, ui, paga, social, news) {

        ui();    

        $(".paginate").paginga({
            // use default options
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like a very modular approach and RequireJS has a lot of different ways to use it. I'll share how I typically have it set up which accomplishes what you are looking for, is streamlined and makes it easy to implement and understand.

I avoid having anything require in my main js completely. First I will create a bundle that includes both the base require.js and a JS file I create called config.js. I will have this bundle loaded in my layout page so it's always available. If you aren't using MVC, the idea is just to make sure Require and my custom config file are always loaded together and always available so do what you need to for that.

Config.js is very simple, in your case just taking your code it will look like this:

```
var require = {
 baseUrl: [system-view:internal]"/render/file.act?path=/assets/scripts/"
 [/system-view:internal] [system-view:external]"/assets/scripts/"[/system-
view:external], 

paths: {
   "jquery": "libs/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min",
    "velocity": "libs/velocity/velocity",
    "bgstretch": "plugins/background-stretch/background-stretch",
    "campus-map": "modules/campus-map",
    "velocity-ui": "libs/velocity/velocity.ui",
    "slick": "plugins/slick/slick",
    "iscroll": "plugins/iscroll/iscroll",
    "dotdotdot": "plugins/dotdotdot/jquery.dotdotdot.min.umd",
    "select": "plugins/select/select",
    "accordion": "modules/accordion",
    "news-filter": "modules/news-filter",
    "codebird": "modules/codebird",
    "social-feed": "modules/social-feed"
},

shim: {

    "slick": ["jquery"],
    "select": ["jquery"],
    "bgstretch": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    "accordion": ["jquery"],
    "codebird": ["jquery"],
    "social-feed": {
        dep: ["jquery", "codebird"],
        exports: "displayFeed"
    },
    "campus-map": {
        deps: [ "jquery" ]
    },
    "velocity": {
        deps: [ "jquery" ]
    },
    "velocity-ui": {
        deps: [ "velocity" ]
    }
    },
     map: {
        '*': {
            'jQuery': 'jquery'
        }
    }
};
```

That's it. I tend to have all of my javascript files associated to each HTML page separated, so in the paths section of the set up I'll have the view name and then the location in my source of the corresponding javascript file. Then in my HTML page when I'm adding in scripts, I'll simply state

```
 <script> require(['sign-in']); </script>
```

This will grab the script file I have defined in the require variable for my view. Then in each script file, sign-in.js for example for this one, I will wrap all of the scrip in a define statement, so at the top of each JS file you can clearly see what dependencies you will load and use in that page. It's clean, it's a framework, it works wonderfully, and it keeps you from loading things you don't need.

In the self contained JS file you would do:

```
define(['jquery', 'lodash', 'bootstrap'], function ($, _) {
   //All JS code here
}):
```

I will have all my libraries that need a selector defined first and then everything else after. That's it, hopefully a real example will help you.

Comment: So where does the main.js file come into play? Also, according to your second comment" Then in my HTML page when I'm adding in scripts, I'll simply state..." Does this mean I have to individually call the needed script for every HTML page? <script> require(['news-filter']);</script> for example.

Comment: I've tried using this header script only on the pages needing the news-filter.js, but I get the error "requrejs is not defined". 
` <script async="" data-main="/render/file.act?path=/assets/scripts/main" src="/assets/scripts/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>[/system-view:internal]
    [system-view:external]
    <script async="" data-main="/assets/scripts/main" src="/assets/scripts/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['news-filter']);
    </script> ` @NardDog

Comment: This was the solution, I just had to remove the baseUrl from the require variable and define it in the actual page as:
` require.config({ baseUrl: [system-view:internal]"/render/file.act?path=/assets/scripts/"[/system-view:internal] [system-view:external]"/assets/scripts/"[/system-view:external]} );

        require(['modules/utils', 'modules/custom.ui', 'libs/jquery/paginga.jquery', 'social-feed', 'news-filter'],
            function (utils, ui, paga, social, news) {
            ui();
            $(".paginate").paginga({  
            });
        }); ` Thanks @Nard Dog and @Louis

Comment: One more thing. Will the config.js file load all the modules that are listed in the "paths" and "shim" objects since they are in a variable named "require"?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing somthing about how reqire.js determines what scripts are needed on each page?

Sure looks like you are. You show a `main.js` file that has this (reformatted to help readability):

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'modules/utils', 'modules/custom.ui',
           'libs/jquery/paginga.jquery', "modules/social-feed",
           "modules/news-filter"],
```

If you use this `main.js` on all your pages, then all the modules you list there are going to be loaded, which means that `modules/news-filter` is going to be loaded on all pages. This, *irrespective* of whether any code actually uses it.

The way RequireJS works, any dependency listed in a `require` call is loaded. And for each module loaded, any dependency they list in their `define` call or in a `shim` set for them in your configuration is also loaded. It does not matter one bit if something is listed but not *actually* used by your code.

---

Tangential remark about your configuration. In your `paths` you have:

```
"news-filter": "modules/news-filter"
```

But then you refer to it as `modules/news-filter` in your `require` call instead of `news-filters`. You should use `news-filter` or remove the mapping you've set in `paths`. RequireJS does now allow referring to the same JavaScript file through two different module names in the same context. If you load your module as `modules/news-filter` in one place and as `news-filter` somewhere else, you're going to run into problems.

If you need to use two different names to access the same JavaScript file, you use `map`. What `map` does is tell RequireJS "when you get a request for module X, load module Y instead". So RequireJS replaces the module name requested with a different one.

Comment: But not all of my modules are listed in the reqirejs() call at the bottom of the main.js. `code` requirejs(

    ['jquery', 'modules/utils', 'modules/custom.ui', 'libs/jquery/paginga.jquery', "modules/social-feed"], 
    function ($, utils, ui, paga, social) {

        ui();    
                
        $(".paginate").paginga({
         // use default options
     });
    }); `code`

Comment: so I should manually add a requirejs(['news-filter']) call on the page that uses the module? If so, how would I do that? Call it after the call to the main.js file? @Louis

Comment: You should tailor the list of required modules to what the page actually requires. There are quite a few ways to do this depending on what your build/release/deploy process is. The most straightforward one is to have a `<script>require([... list of modules needed by the page...])</script>` after you load RequireJS and its configuration.

Comment: I've tried that and I keep getting various "something is not a function" ($ is not a function)
`  <script src="/assets/scripts/config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/scripts/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        require(['jquery', 'modules/utils', 'modules/custom.ui', 'libs/jquery/paginga.jquery', 'social-feed', 'news-filter'],
            function ($, utils, ui, paga, social, news) {
            $(".paginate").paginga({
            });
        });
    </script> ` @Louis